# Add a WPF UserControl to a TaskPane

Tags: wpf, outlook-addin, customtaskpane

I am developing an addin to Microsoft Outlook.

The following code works fine if I use an winforms UserControl:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{            
    var testControlView1 = new UserControl1();
    var MyCustomPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(testControlView, "Hello");
}
```

How can I do it with a WPF UserControl, instead? Does anybody know how I would achieve similar functionality?

As far as I can tell the CustomTaskPanes only allow Winforms Controls to be added to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found a solution,
https://stevepietrekweblog.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/vsto-display-wpf-user-control-in-custom-task-pane/

This update was just to update the link.

Comment: This link is dead :(

Comment: @Xmindz https://stevepietrekweblog.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/vsto-display-wpf-user-control-in-custom-task-pane/ hope this can help you